# How is this code converting binary to integer values using ord()?

Tags: python

```
B = '1101'
I = 0
while B != '':
  I = I * 2 + (ord(B[0]) - ord('0'))
  B = B[1:]
```

This code convert binary to integer using `ord` function in python.
Mathematical conversion for this case is `1 * 2^3 + 1 * 2^2 + 0 * 2^1 + 1 * 2^0 = 13` (answer for the given input).
I am also not expecting the translation code of this math. but I would like to know how the given code conforms/translates to the math logic to give the desired result. could someone explain the  math/logic behind the code?

Comment: Which part don't you understand? It might help to add `print(I)` as the first line of the loop.

Comment: Well, `ord(B[0]) - ord('0')` will be either `1` or `0`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to understand is `ord(B[0]) - ord('0')`. This is basically a hacky way of converting the character at `B[0]` to a number. Since 0 and 1 are right next to each other on the ASCII table, `ord('0') - ord('0')` is 0 and `ord('1') - ord('0')` is 1.

The loop itself simply does stuff on the first character (`B[0]`), then slices it to remove the first character (`B = B[1:]`), and goes until it's empty. For every character, it multiplies `I` by 2 to essentially make room for another digit, then adds the digit to `I` to set the digit. Think about if you had base 10, with the number `456`. You'd start with `0`, then add the first digit to get `4`. You'd then multiply by 10 to make space for another digit, so you'd have `40`, then you'd add the second digit to get `45`. You'd then multiply by 10 again to get `450`, then add the third digit to get `456`. Except, in this case, it's binary so you multiply by 2.

Comment: exactly what i was looking for.thank you.